# findall returning only the last attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, findall

i have searched for similar questions but didn't find what i need.

I am searching a web for two attributes in this case `red` and `green` in `span`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
nameList=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"red","class":"green"})
print(nameList)
```

However i am only getting the green attribute,i tried using

```
nameList,nameList2=soup.findAll("span",{"class":"red","class":"green"})
```

but i get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`
is there a way to print both and store each attribute in a namelist (without using multiple `findAll`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use CSS selector to match `span` with both class names as below:

```
nameList = soup.select("span.red, span.green")
```

If you still want to use `findAll`, try

```
nameList = soup.findAll("span",{"class":["red", "green"]})
```

Comment: it works, is there a way to store red alone and green alone?

Comment: @timmy , `soup.select("span.red, span.green")` select both, `soup.select("span.green")` select green only, `soup.select("span.red")` select red only

Comment: @Andersson i understand,this a fine method. However why is `findAll` not storing both attributes?

Comment: @timmy , because you should pass class names as list: `soup.findAll("span",{"class":["red","green"]})`

Comment: this method works,but leaves no way for storing each alone right ?

Comment: @timmy , none of available methods will allow you to make two separate lists with the single query...

Comment: in that case there is no reason to use `findAll` with multiple attributes (not as list) since it will show only the last one. i am sorry if i seem in "attack mode"  :-D

Comment: @timmy I thought you want to combine two queries in single one, not to separate them... In this case two `findAll` is the proper approach

Answer (score 0):

As your red and green are the only class attributes you can just check for span with class attribute

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
nameList=soup.select("span[class]")
print(nameList)
```

To have separate lists you can use 2 selects by class name:

```
reds = soup.select('span.red')
greens = soup.select('span.green')
print(reds,greens)
```

Comment: how can i store red alone and green alone without using multiple select?